# Short break with Handler?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a short time break with a Handler. I made a test like this:

```
Log.i("Test","Brake start!");
handler1.postDelayed(this, 500);
Log.i("Test","Brake end!");
```

But there seems to be no break! The text in LogCat is running constantly. I need this short break to move a sprite object to a certain position and then make a check, but without any breaks the code is doing it all at once and the sprite object does not reach it's target before the check has been done.

Am I using the Handler incorrectly or is there a better way to get a short break? I'm running my code inside a game loop in a class that implements Runnable. Looking forward to get some tips!

Comment: PostDelayed method is an asynchronous call, it causes specified runnable to be added to Handler Message queue to execute after specified time and immediately returns executing next line. If you have this code in run() method, then you will see 500 delay between Brake end and next Brake start.

Comment: what you mean: "But there seems to be no brake!"?

Comment: @pskink I mean that the text in LogCat is running all the time, should there not be a brake of 500 between each row of text?

Comment: @Anirudh I have this code inside the run() method!?

Comment: yes there should be a break of 500 ms, how did you verify that there is no break, change 500 to 5000 and see what happens

Comment: I have also tested 5000, but no progress!

Comment: handler.removeCallbacks(Runnable r); you forgot to stop the handler after the delay so it keeps running.

Comment: @3D-kreativ you want just a 5 second delay? in that case you need to stop the handler after 5 seconds otherwise it will keep running until you stop it

Comment: @Raghunandan 5 seconds was just a test to see if it was working. I think it will work now with some help of the answer below.

Comment: @3D-kreativ so what is that you actually want. to keep running something every 5 seconds?

Comment: @Raghunandan No, I just want a short time delay when a boolean value belonging to a sprite object is set to true. The sprite object is moving in one direction, a check is done to see if it was a valid move and if it wasn't a valid move, then the sprite object should return back in the oppesite direction. Without any time brakes, things happens to fast and the sprite objects even don't reach it's target position before it moves back! Complicated to explain what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Log.i("Test","Brake start!");
handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         Log.i("Test","Brake end!");
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work! I set the value to 5000, and text is still running in LogCat without any breaks. What could be wrong?

Comment: Now it seems to work. I put your code inside a method that I call when I need a short brake. I'm new to this, just wonder how this work? Will other stuff like other moving sprites be affected by this brake or will the other code be running as normal? Do I have to remove the handler like in the comment above written by Raghunandan?

Comment: @3D-kreativ Other code will run normally during this time. When posting `Runnable`, you add code in the `run()` to be executed at a later time. You will not need to remove unless you create a pseudo-loop out of it. And there is this case of temporal memory leak: you need to remove if your `Activity` is destroyed before break ends.

Comment: Ok, so there will be no conflicts with the other run() method that is inside the main game loop then? Could this code be implementet anywere or only in classes that implements Runnable? Just curious, what is a pseudo-loop?

Comment: @3D-kreativ If the other `run()` is executed on a background thread, there will be no conflict, but you don't really need a `Handler` in that case. If you have a bunch of fast code on main thread, there will be no problem either. "Pseudo-loop" is my name for periodically called code, e.g. in [DemoActivity.java](https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/source/browse/android-maps-extensions-demo/src/pl/mg6/android/maps/extensions/demo/DemoActivity.java) look for `dataUpdater` and also in `onResume` / `onPause`.

Comment: Sorry for a very long discussen, but you wrote that I didn't need a handler if I had a Thread in the background!? I guess I'm running a thread in the background, but I'm not sure. But how would you do then to get a short time delay?

Comment: @3D-kreativ Store current time at some point and check against time passed on next iterations of the loop. You may want to ask a question for that with gaming-related tags (or better search for it first, because I'm pretty sure someone already asked it here).